# How does Qt program monitor keyboard while hiding?

Tags: c++, windows, qt, winapi

I create a Qt program and it normally stay as a tray on the right bottom of the screen. I need to use keyboard to active it, such as CTRL+ALT+A. But I can not find way to implement it. I searched a lot of information and it seems that using native windows API helps.

I'm here asking is there anyone knows how to do this with Qt or with windows API.

Comment: [`SetWindowsHookEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644990(VS.85).aspx)

Comment: Or `QxtGlobalShortcut`: http://libqxt.bitbucket.org/doc/tip/qxtglobalshortcut.html